# I'm trying to remove all my symbolic links to python 3.9

Tags: python, macos

I'm trying to remove python 3.9 complete from my macOS High Sierra,

I have manually delete the folder python 3.9 from my applications folder.

I have used the following commands to remove it from library.

```bash
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
```

When a list the broken links it shows me all the broken links:

```bash
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep ../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
```

OUTPUT:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         66 Jun 14 19:49 2to3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/2to3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         70 Jun 14 19:49 2to3-3.9 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/2to3-3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         67 Jun 14 19:49 idle3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/idle3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         69 Jun 14 19:49 idle3.9 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/idle3.9
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin         66 Jun 14 19:50 pip3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin         68 Jun 14 19:50 pip3.9 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pip3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         68 Jun 14 19:49 pydoc3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pydoc3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         70 Jun 14 19:49 pydoc3.9 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/pydoc3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         69 Jun 14 19:49 python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         76 Jun 14 19:49 python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         71 Jun 14 19:49 python3.9 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel         78 Jun 14 19:49 python3.9-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9-config
```

But when i try to remove the symbolic links to it says "No such file or directory found"

I'm using these command:

```bash
cd /usr/local/bin

ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm*
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python; the python tags are useless here. This seems to be more a question for eg SuperUser.

Comment: `xargs rm*`? That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: There's only about 10 links; just remove them manually instead.

Comment: I don't know how to remove them manually, If you could help @9769953 that would be great.

Comment: You don't know about (`sudo`) `rm path-to-symlink`?? How did you come up with that piped commandline then?

Comment: I know the path but when i'm running the `rm` command it says `No such file or directory found`. As you can see in the question that it exist when i `ls` the links.

Comment: You don't show running `rm` by itself on the symbolic link. You only show a complicated piped command.